# Is there a better way to do it : Joins on different Datatables?

Tags: c#, join, datatable

I want to perform a `JOIN` on two Datatables in a Dataset. For example, I am working on the AdventureWorks database. I need data from the tables `[Person].[Address]` and `[Person].[StateProvince]` and once the data is in the corresponding Datatables, I have to perform a `JOIN` on `StateProvinceID` column.

Data Structure -

```
Address {Address,A_StateID}
State {S_StateID,Name}
```

My search on the internet led me to a lot of examples which said I will have to use a Datarelation object in order to perform a `JOIN`. The examples I found were like -

```
DataColumn childcolumn = dsAdd.Tables["Address"].Columns["A_StateID"];
DataColumn parentcolumn = dsAdd.Tables["State"].Columns["S_StateID"];
DataRelation relStateID = new DataRelation("StateRel", parentcolumn, childcolumn,false);
dsAdd.Relations.Add(relStateID);
```

But, I have no idea what I have to do after I have added a DataRelation to perform the `JOIN`. So, I decided to do it myself -

```
    //I added a new column to my Address table obtain the State Name after performing the `JOIN`
    DataColumn A_State = new DataColumn("State");
    A_State.DataType = typeof(string);
    dsAdd.Tables["Address"].Columns.Add(A_State);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dsAdd.Tables["Address"].Rows)
    {           
        //for each row in the Address table I obtain the StateID
        string stateid = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString();
        string expression = "S_StateID =" + stateid;

        //Obtain the corresponding row from State table and update the value in new column in Address table 
        DataRow[] newdr;
        newdr = dsAdd.Tables["State"].Select(expression);
        string statename = newdr[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        dr.SetField("State", statename.ToString());
    }

    grdJoins.DataSource = dsAdd.Tables["Address"];
    grdJoins.DataBind();
```

This works fine but is there a better way to do this? How is a `JOIN` performed using a Datarelation object?

Comment: BTW...I hope this is a legacy app you're working on and not using DatSets for new development.

Comment: Should a dataset not be used at all? why? Are the performance drawbacks of the dataset so profound?

Comment: Not performance, there are just better tools out there.  Take a look at [What are the advantages of using an ORM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398134/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-an-orm) as a starting point.

Comment: @Pavan - datasets should be reserved for truly _disconnected_ scenarios: for example, you're building an app for a smart phone or other remote device that won't always have direct access to your data. The performance problem with datasets is two-fold: they are memory hogs (all of the data is memory at once) and they preclude any possibility of _real_ lazy evaluation/data streaming.  The alternative that fixes these problems is the DataReader

Comment: @R0MANARMY ORMs aren't exactly all that great, either -- more like a crutch, really.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: ORMs certainly have their limitations, but I would still consider them a step up from straight up DataSets.  As far as disconnected scenarios, I would say something like [Sql Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) would be a better choice given it supports [Sync Services for ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx).  It may not be a perfect solution but is probably still better than rolling your own synchronization framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *best* way to do this is to do it on the database.  Joins are relatively expensive and slow operations; databases exist as entities separate from mere collections of tables for two reasons: enforcing safe concurrent access and *to allow you do joins efficiently.*  They use all kinds of tricks like indexing, materialized views, caching, etc, to make sure most of the heavy lifting is already done for you.

The next best way is to use linq (to objects):

```
grdJoins.DataSource = dsAdd.Tables["Address"].AsEnumerable()
                .Join(dsAdd.Tables["State"].AsEnumerable(),
        add => add["A_StateID"], st => st["S_StateID"],
        (add, st) => new 
      { 
          Address = add["Address"],
          City = add["City"],
          StateProvince = add["StateProvince"],
          State = st["State"]
      });

grdJoins.DataBind();
```

Comment: Did you mean [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) instead of Linq to Objects (since you're starting out with a DataSet instead of a regular collection)?

Comment: @R0MANARMY only in the sense that linq to dataset is really just a part of linq to objects.  Note the call to AsEnumerable() - it's using the same pieces as any other linq to objects enumerable.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - linq to datasets is just a straight enumeration over a dataset.  It's just a marketing name for what's already there.  The linq to datasets samples all have to call AsEnumerale() as well.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for clarifying.  Thankfully I haven't had to use them very heavily (at all really).

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand what you're asking correctly, once you've added a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx) you can make a call to [GetChildRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbt8xha8.aspx) on a given row to get the *joined* data.  The documentation has an example of what the code should look like.